# List custom created directory roles programmatically

Tags: azure-rbac, azure-identity

I created some custom directory roles with specific permissions. I have to list these custom roles in a programmatic way.

This gives list of all directory roles in Graph

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/roleManagement/directory/roleDefinitions

Attempted changing query with filter but throwing Bad Request

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/roleManagement/directory/roleDefinitions?$filter=isBuiltIn eq 'false'

> {
> "error": {
> "code": "BadRequest",
> "message": "Invalid filter clause",
> "innerError": {
> "date": "2022-12-07T04:25:04",
> "request-id": "09f4f286-8088-4a17-881b-584377fe8c58",
> "client-request-id": "638047c0-e1e5-40e0-b166-416aacd1cc6a"
> } } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

In Azure Portal, I applied **filter** with **`Type: Custom`** and got custom directory roles as below:

[image]

To get this list from Graph API, I ran the **same query** as you and got **same error** as below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/roleManagement/directory/roleDefinitions?$filter=isBuiltIn eq 'false'
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, I modified the query and got the results successfully like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/roleManagement/directory/roleDefinitions?$filter=(isBuiltIn eq false)&$select=displayName,id,isBuiltIn
```

**Response:**

[image]